# Theoretically speaking, would a Dreidle be Muqse on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, chanuka, games-toys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are dreidels muktzah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4055/are-dreidels-muktzah)

Would there be any problem with Dreidels on Shabbat? I discussed it with some people and we couldn't find any Halachic issues with it.